Decomposition of a non-smooth function into a particular form
I am new to convex optimization but I have to read Nesterov's paper "Smooth approximation of non-smooth functions" for a project. However while reading the paper, I've hit a roadblock, any help is appreciated.
Let $f: Q_1 \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous convex function on a convex set. The goal is to find a decomposition $$f(x) = \hat f (x) + \max_u\{\langle Ax,u\rangle_2 - \hat \phi(u) : u \in Q_2\}$$ where $\hat f$ is a continuous convex function on $Q_1$, $Q_2$ is a closed convex bounded set in a finite-dimensional real vector space $E_2$, $\hat \phi$ is a continuous convex function on $Q_2$ and $A: E_1 \to E_2^*$ is a linear operator. Such a decomposition is not unique.
My question is in the case where $f(x) = \max_{1\leq j \leq m} |\langle a_j, x\rangle - b^{(j)}|$. If we set $A = I_{E_1}$, $E_2 = E_1^* = \mathbb R^n$ and $\hat f = 0$ then we can set
$$\hat \phi(u) = \max_x\{\langle u, x\rangle_1 - \max_{1\leq j \leq m} |\langle a_j, x\rangle - b^{(j)}|$$
which is the convex conjugate of $f$ and this works because $f$ is convex continuous and since $\hat f = 0$, $f$ is the convex conjugate of $\hat \phi$.
However $\hat \phi$ can be simplified:
\begin{align}
\hat \phi(u) &= \max_x\{\langle u, x\rangle_1 - \max_{1\leq j \leq m} |\langle a_j, x\rangle - b^{(j)}|\\
 &=\max_x \min_{s\in \mathbb R^m} \left\{ \langle u, x\rangle_1 - \sum_{j=1}^m s^{(j)} [\langle a_j, x\rangle - b^{(j)}] : \sum_{j=1}^m |s^{(j)}| \leq 1 \right\}\\
&= \min_{s\in \mathbb R^n}\left\{ \sum_{j=1}^m s^{(j)}b^{(j)} : u = \sum_{j=1}^m s^{(j)}a_j, \sum_{j=1}^m |s^{(j)}| \leq 1 \right\}
\end{align}
The first equality (introducing $s \in \mathbb R^m$) is clear. I do not understand the second equality.
Since this function is linear in $x$ and $s$, we can swap the order of $\max_x$ and $\min_s$.
\begin{align}
\hat \phi (u) &= 
\max_x \min_{s\in \mathbb R^m} \left\{ \langle u, x\rangle_1 - \sum_{j=1}^m s^{(j)} [\langle a_j, x\rangle - b^{(j)}] : \sum_{j=1}^m |s^{(j)}| \leq 1 \right\}\\
&= \min_{s\in \mathbb R^m}\max_x\left\{ \langle u, x\rangle_1 - \sum_{j=1}^m s^{(j)} [\langle a_j, x\rangle - b^{(j)}] : \sum_{j=1}^m |s^{(j)}| \leq 1 \right\}
\end{align}
But now it is not clear to me on how to proceed and why would all the maximums lie in the subset $u = \sum_{j=1}^m s^{(j)}a_j, \sum_{j=1}^m |s^{(j)}| \leq 1 $?
Edit: Is it because the maximum will blow up to infinity if the coefficient of $x$ is not zero since $Q_1$ is probably implicitly taken to be all of $\mathbb R$ and thus the operand for those values of $u$ can never appear appear as minimum?
